# Redactor show only one instance at a time

Tags: jquery, redactor

I have a condition in which I have to search for a particular class through out the document and on click of that class initialize the redactor.

I have done this by traversing html and

```
$(".contenteditor").redactor({
    toolbarExternal: '.commoneditor',
    toolbarFixed: true,
    focus       : true,
    imageUpload : 'image_upload.php',
    css         : "http://localhost/template/css/basictemplatepage.css",
});
```

Suppose there is more than one element with same class and both should trigger redactor. In that case I am coming up with more than one instance of redactor which is not working properly. I just want to destroy all previous instances and keep only one instance of redactor. How can I do that ??

Answer (score 0):

You can instantiate the redactor on `click` by using the `this` keyword which references the `clicked` element.

```
$(".contenteditor").on('click', function(event){

$(this).redactor({
    toolbarExternal: '.commoneditor',
    toolbarFixed: true,
    focus       : true,
    imageUpload : 'image_upload.php',
    css         : "http://localhost/template/css/basictemplatepage.css",
});
});
```

Comment: I have almost done the same thing
$(this).addClass("contenteditor");
and then invoked the editor using this added class..